# How to get view of invisible items in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a problem with `RecyclerView` of select its `itemview`. I searched for hours but still not found the answer. Here is my code:

```
              for (int i = 0; i < mAdapter.getItemCount(); i++) {
                View view = recyclerView.getChildAt(i);
                if (view != null) {
                    TextView tvIdEnt = view.findViewById(R.id.goodID_ENT_GOOD);
                    TextView tvName = view.findViewById(R.id.goodNAME_ENT_GOOD);
                    TextView tvQuan = view.findViewById(R.id.goodQUANTITY_GOOD);

                    if (!tvQuan.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                        hasGood = true;
                        String idEnt = tvIdEnt.getText().toString();
                        String name = tvName.getText().toString();
                        int qty = Integer.parseInt(tvQuan.getText().toString());

                        //insert good                  
                    }
                }
            }
```

My `mAdapter` has 10 elements. When I used `ListView`, I got 10 child views, perfect. But when I used `RecyclerView`, it just returns visible items. Example, method `getChildAt(0)` will be returned the first visible item on the screen, not the real first item - the first item of `mAdapter`. How can I get all 10 items of the `RecyclerView`?

Comment: you can't get all 10 items, as they don't exist. It creates only enopugh views to fill the screen + 1 on top + 1 on bottom. Then when the view goes out off screen, it is recycled (reused) and used for the other list item that is coming on screen next. List View is working in simillar way, and if you had all 10 views with it, it means that you implemented it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can set views in `ViewHolder`. Sample `RecyclerView` adapter;

```
/**
* Created by beyazid on 11.04.2019.
*/
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ArrayList<String> list;

public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> list) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_row_for_recycler_view, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.bindItem(position);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

}


public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView tvDummy;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvDummy = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
    }
    void bindItem(int pos) {
        String txt = list.get(pos);
        tvDummy.setText(txt);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not possible because `Recyclerview` uses the same View for every index.
That is the Positive point between `ListView` vs `RecyclerView`.